# Check if point is in polygon or not

Tags: google-maps

There is some region on the map, and I have to check is user placed marker on this region. The problem is how to declare this "rectangular", how to declare bounds with lat and lng..

Maybe someone wants to know details: I am developing web application for taxi company. So, user will declare original and destinatoin by putting 2 markers. And the center of the city, the square with 12X12 km. has constant tarif nearly 10$. And tarif for other destinations (outside square) is calculated from tarif by km. from db.

Answer (score 0):

there may be many ways, 1 possible:

create a `google.maps.Circle` with the center set to the center of the city and a radius of 12000.

All you have to check now if the destination is placed within the bounds of the circle.

```
definedCircle.getBounds().contains(destinationLatLng)
```

Answer (score 0):

check this...

[Google-Maps-Point-in-Polygon](https://github.com/tparkin/Google-Maps-Point-in-Polygon)